# PHP session Mountain Lion

Tags: php, osx-mountain-lion

So using the default php version on my mac, I am trying to enable php sessions. I went into /etc/php.ini and uncommented the following and it still is not being detected as enabled in Impress Pages

```
session.save_path = "/tmp"
session.use_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 1
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you restart apache?

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the file as the root user? If that didn't work, use something like MAMP like I do. :)

Comment: Yes I did sudo vim it. MAMP is no fun. I am wondering if something in php land in not installed on the mac side of things

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It was enabled it was just the application I was using was false reporting that it did not work. Sorry about that guys